# Installing websphere in AIX (Unix)

Tags: unix, aix, websphere

I want to install web-sphere 6.1 in machine which has `AIX OS`. What is the command to install it? I need to install it from telnet.

I have using tried the following command, but the installation doesn't start:

`./install –options responsefile.base.txt -silent`

Where **response.base.txt** file contains parameters used at the time of installation

Would someone please help me. I've already spent lot of time trying to solve this problem..

Comment: This question needs some editing, the question is unclear. And btw.: AIX isn't Linux, it's a flavour of Unix.

Comment: Did you check the Information Center? http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/wsbroker/redirect?version=pix&product=was-nd-dist&topic=tins_runsilent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, the easiest way, (if you're new to AIX/WAS), is to export your display and install it using the GUI.

So depending on how you have your system setup:

```
export DISPLAY=<your IP>:0.0

./launch-installer-gui
```

Make sure you have a program running on your client side, like exceed, to create the gui.